# Portfolio diversification into different currencies

Tags: foreign-exchange, currency, portfolio, foreign-currency

Does it make sense to diversify the portfolio into different currencies if they are in any case correlated with each other or is it not so?

Comment: Are you asking about an investment portfolio, e.g. stocks/ETFs?

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea no, I ask about investment into foreign currency’s